# There are topological spaces that admit differentiable non-diffeomorphic structures?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

There are topological spaces that admit differentiable non-diffeomorphic structures?
hello I am trying to find out if for a topological space with two differentiable structures they can be non-diffeomorphic from each other.
For example consider $R$ whit the parametrization $f(x)=x^3$ and also with the trivial parametrization $g(x)=x$, they define two differentiable structures that are distinct but diffeomorphic from each other.

Comment: Consider exotic spheres. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere

Comment: There is a really weird theorem: $\mathbb{R}^n$ has one unique (up to diffeomorphism) differentiable structure, unless $n=4$, for which there exist an infinite non-countable amount of differentiable structures.

Comment: Could you give me the name of a book..? I'm really interested in the "weird theorem." Thank you

Comment: @GabrielCanedo This [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_R4) has many references you could look at.

Comment: Understanding these (Milnor's) examples will be hard. The only textbook treatment I know is in the book by Antoni A. Kosinski, "Differential manifolds." He gets there on page 216. But first, you would need to learn basic algebraic topology (homotopy and homology groups).